Ubuntu 24 Virtualbox 7 Guest - Display Issues
I did a fresh install of virtualbox and Ubuntu 24. I'm getting issues with 3d acceleration on and off. When it's on, everything runs really nicely, but system windows don't render properly (shown below). I can't figure out how to resolve this issue.


For others seeing this question - I've concluded a couple things: 1) Maybe better to stick with Ubuntu 22 for a while until these kinks get sorted out (I'm not sure if this issue exists on 22 still). 2) Try avoiding virtualization for my rails development environment. I tried WSL2 with windows and I LOVE IT so far. WSL2 Ubuntu with visual studio code and I get mostly everything I need while having linux tooling.

I was able to solve this iuuse by turning off 3D Acceleration in Display settings of the VM. How to Disable 3D acceleration in VirtualBox
